How to successfully build and run an old Flutter project with the new Flutter SDK?
Is there any working or reliable procedure on how to build and run an old (not too) Flutter project with the new Flutter SDK?
I'm desperately looking for a somehow well structured MVVM or Bloc sample on Flutter but what ever I've found on Github or elsewhere are not able to run with Flutter SDK v. 3.24.5.
I have searched and found some articles on Medium and videos on Youtube but non of the could help 100%!
With all of projects I have found, I faced with errors complaining about the following issues for only running on an Android device:

My java version
My Flutter SDK Version
My Dart version
Flutter packages version incompatibility
Android Gradle version
etc....

And I did what ever they were complaining about as a fix but just another error appeared afterwards again and again and it was an unlimited loop!
Do you have any solution or may be any example which you could run successfully with the new Flutter SDK?

Not sure, but try to remove the build folder of flutter project, as it clears out all cached artifacts and forces Flutter to rebuild everything from scratch using the updated version of the SDK. This can help resolve issues caused by mismatches between the SDK and outdated build files.

What you can try is create a new flutter project and then copy all your codes to the new project and try running for there. If it does not run, then you got to fix everything step by step. First, your java version should be 17

@DroidFlutter I did that as well but not so helpful unfortunately.

@Md.KamrulAmin also tried this approach but not easy at all to migrate all packages to the new project

If you are unwilling to do that. Your best case scenario is to fix all your given errors one by one. Your first error is cause of Java. So, if you upgraded to Android Studio ladybug, you need to make sure you use Java 17 when building with flutter. You also need to migrate a lot of packages in your pubspec.yaml. There is no easy way out here.

I also moved the project from flutter 2.8.1 to 3.24.5, I changed lots of things and files.

First I fixed the pubspec.yaml with all the deprecated properties. If the package is not compaitble or depends on other package I didn't upgrade till I solve the updated packages issue.
Then I fix the gradle version issue and totally changed the gradle template to new version for that I created sample project with 3.24.5 and use that template with new old project dependency once I updated it to the gradle then I fix the version issue mostly (kotlin, gradle version)

